# SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: "cannot find TABLE specified by DD01L"

Tags: sap-dotnet-connector

I wanted to use the SAP .NET Connector to get some data from an SAP Server but unfortunately I'm running into this error with my code:

> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: "cannot find TABLE specified by DD01L"

This is the part of the code that's not working:

```
RfcStructureMetadata lineType = destination.Repository.GetTableMetadata("DD01L").LineType;
String[] colS = new string[lineType.FieldCount];

for (int i = 0; i < colS.Length; i++)
{
    colS[i] = lineType[i].Name;
    Console.WriteLine("%s\n", colS[i]);
}
```

Comment: So the error message status that the table "DD01L" is missing. Did you check whether it exists?

Comment: @Capricorn yes, in the SAP GUI Programm for Windows I can see the table when I connect to the server.

Comment: I'm seeing this with RfcInvalidStateException: cannot find TABLE specified by EDI_DD40 while fetching IDOC metadata. This is a standard table for IDOC present on the target system. I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

It Is a transparent table. So maybe this is the reason. Look here.: https://www.tcodesearch.com/sap-tables/DD01L#table-structure

If it is working with other tables then this is it.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answer, `DD01L` is a database table.

The method `GetTableMetadata` is to be used for working with RFC function parameters which are of the type "TABLES" and work with their technical properties.

If you want to read a database table, you may call specialized functions via SAP .NET Connector. One generic function is named `RFC_READ_TABLE`.